# Why is the background color of my drawable view black?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, background-color

I would like the `backgroundColor` property of my `UIView` to be red or yellow. Though, the view displays a black color.

```
class RenderView:UIView {

    var pointsToDraw:[Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3);
        UIColor.yellowColor().set()


        if pointsToDraw.count > 4 {

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGFloat(pointsToDraw[0]), CGFloat(pointsToDraw[1]))

            for i in 2..<pointsToDraw.count {
                if i % 2 == 0 {
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(pointsToDraw[i]), CGFloat(pointsToDraw[i + 1]))
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

The line I can draw on the view is yellow, but the view is still black. [Here's a sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmc8k4y48qodlxx/DBPathRecognizer.zip?dl=0). Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to call `CGContextClearRect`? It's clearing the background color - and then you never re-draw your own background. Therefore the result will be black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling `CGContextClearRect`. The effect of this call can be quite tricky (as I explain [in my online book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_paths_and_drawing)). If you want the view's background to be red, then at the start of your `drawRect:` you should fill the context's bounds with red.